# Detect if you're in the “Frontend Editor” mode in Visual Composer Wordpress

Tags: plugins, theme-development

Marketo forms tend to break the Wordpress Frontend Editor.

Now - my thoughts are to detect if I am just displaying the current page or I am in the frontend editor mode. If in frontend editor mode just to replace the normal form output with a placeholder (or just not display the JavaScript that breaks everything).

If somebody has any better suggestion - do not hestitate to!

Comment: You will need to ask the visual composer developers, or check it’s documentation. 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here.

Comment: Their support is not available at this moment... And I'm sure there's a lot of people that used and had this kind of experience because there's a lot of scripts that VC doesn't like.

Comment: I'm sorry guys but Visual Composer is a widely used plugin. A lot of people don't have the license to open a ticket because they are customizing a premium theme that don't provide a license for it.
I don't mean to be rude, but telling me that it's personal - is unprofessional because I'm sure people will be searching for this kind of topic.
Hope you have a nice day - cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've dig in the core of WPBakery Visual Composer and came up with this solution:

```
function is_vc_build() {
    return function_exists( 'vc_is_inline' ) && vc_is_inline() ? true : false;
}
```

Hope it will help somebody in future as I spent lots of time on this.